# "[T]ransversely isotropic and mirror-symmetric (space group:$D_{\infty h}$)", its orbifold notation?

Tags: notation, definition, symmetry, orbifolds

I am trying to understand this frieze pattern $D_{\infty h}$ aka its orbifold notation. This describes spider's silk. The [authors](http://www.nature.com/nmat/journal/v12/n3/full/nmat3549.html) call it a [space group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_group), some sort of generalization from orbifolds.

Please, explain the term *"[T]ransversely isotropic and mirror-symmetric (space group:$D_{\infty h}$)"* in Conway-and-Thurston notation aka orbifold notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This frieze group ($D_{\infty h}$) is called $*22\infty$ in orbifold notation or $p2mm$ in the crystallographers' notation.  Like other [frieze groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frieze_group), it is a group of plane symmetries which contains a one-dimensional lattice of translations.  If you take the generator of the translational lattice to be in a horizontal direction, then the group can be generated by this translation together with a reflection about a horizontal line and a reflection about a vertical line.  This is why it is being called transversely isotropic and mirror-symmetric.  The group also contains other symmetries generated by these such as additional reflections about vertical lines, $180^\circ$ rotations, and glide-reflections.

The [orbifold notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbifold_notation) comes from taking a quotient of the plane by the symmetry group.  After doing this, you no longer have a $2$-manifold (something locally homeomorphic to the plane) but an [orbifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbifold), which is locally homeomorphic to quotients of the plane.  The $*$ denotes the presence of a boundary crease where the orbifold has been folded upon itself by reflectional symmetry.  The two $2$s denote the presence of two corner points in this crease where vertical mirrors meet the horizontal mirror.  The $\infty$ symbolizes the open end of the orbifold at vertical infinity.

For a picture of a plane figure with this symmetry, see for example [here](http://mathdl.maa.org/images/upload_library/4/vol1/architecture/Math/seven.html), where the group is called $F_7$, or [here](http://illuminations.nctm.org/ActivityDetail.aspx?ID=168), where it is called Class IV.